# Special character (ex ".") not able to read from CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am making import/export function for e commerce website. Function that import inventory is working well. But there on problem is there. When i write any special character(e.g. ".", ",") inside inventory field then this character replace with "??".

So, Anyone can help me to fixed that issue?

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your PHP code?

Comment: $file = "inventory.csv"
while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($row);
 echo "</pre>";  
}

Comment: Such problems are often due to that the CSV is created with Windows/ISO encoding and PHP working with UTF-8. Check the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
        $csvContent = file_get_contents( $fileName );
        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $csvContent, 
                                        array("UTF-8","UTF-32","UTF-32BE","UTF-32LE","UTF-16","UTF-16BE","UTF-16LE"), 
                                        TRUE );

        if( $fileEncoding !== "UTF-8" ) {
             $csvContent = mb_convert_encoding($csvContent, "UTF-8", $fileEncoding );
        }

        foreach( explode( PHP_EOL, $csvContent ) as $item ) {
           var_dump($item );
        }
```

Comment: Had took one field like "test...". Then "...." will automatically remove in result.